# django model query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Model:

```
class Program (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    add = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Subject (models.Model):
    s_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
    s_add = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In a database i have same rows already added, like:

in app_program table:

```
 id | name      |  add
 1  | Program1  |  some date
 2  | Program2  |  some date
 3  | Program3  |  some date
```

in app_subject:

```
 id | s_name    | program | add
 1  | subject1  | 1       | some date
 2  | subject2  | 2       | some date
 3  | subject3  | 1       | some date
 4  | subject4  | 2       | some date
 5  | subject5  | 3       | some date
```

Now in my template, i want to display data in a for loop like this:

```
 1. Program1
     1. subject1
     2. subject3

 2. Program2
     1. subject2
     2. subject4

 3. Program3
     1. subject5
```

I don't know what to put in my views, and in my template. I've tried:

```
 from app.models import Program, Subject
    program_all = Program.objects.all()
    subject_all = Subject.objects.all()
```

then i pass it into templates as context variable etc. and when i use this in template:

```
 {% for field in program_all %}
      {{ forloop.counter }}. {{ field.name }}
      {% for field2 in subject_all %}
      {{ field2.s_name }}
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

it just display all Programs with every existing Subject, and I want to see only a Subject connected with Program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
{% for field in program_all %}
  {{ forloop.counter }}.{{ field.name }}
  {% for subject in field.subject_set.all %}
     {{ forloop.counter }}. {{ subject.s_name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you have a relationship in your model, you can [follow it backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) as well.

In this case, for each `program`, there is a `subject_set` which is all subjects related to that program. In your view or the django shell it would be like this:

```
for p in Program.objects.all():
   print 'The program {} has {} subjects:'.format(p,p.subject_set.count())
   for subject in p.subject_set.all():
       print subject
```